# Error handling concurrent Task.Run calls in C#

Tags: c#, multithreading, exception

I have a function that does a lot of work and is CPU intensive...essentially I have a lot of files that need quite a bit of processing.  So I kick off many threads to handle these.  Here is some pseudo code.

```
bool DoWork(FileInfo fi)
{
    // do lots of work
}

static Task<bool> DoWorkAsync(FileInfo fi)
{
    return Task.Run(() => DoWork(fi));
}


void Main()
{
    DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(somePath);
    List<FileInfo> files = di.GetFiles("*.txt"); // grab all text files in path

    List<Task<bool>> tasks = new List<Task<bool>>();

    foreach (FileInfo fi in files)
    {
        tasks.Add(DoWorkAsync(fi));
    }

    Task.WhenAll();
}
```

However if one task throws an exception, I don't want it to affect the production of the others.  I do want to know about it for logging and handling purposes, but I want to gather successful results and exceptions all at the end (after the `WhenAll` call).

**Update** Per comments below it is suggested I use `WaitAll` and that will throw an `AggregateException`.  However I'm still seeing behavior that is not caught.  Modified my code to look like the following

```
bool DoWork(FileInfo fi) { throw new NotImplementedException();}
```

Then wrapped `WaitAll` like so

```
try
{
    Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());
}
catch (AggregateException aggregateException)
{
    //handle this
}
```

Comment: So what is the problem exactly? Probably you mean not WhenAll but WaitAll? If so - it will wait for all tasks to finish, whether they throw exceptions or not. WhenAll will also complete only when all tasks complete or fail. So exception inside one task won't affect others.

Comment: Don't wrap a function in a `Task.Run` and call it async, [it is a bad habit to have](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/03/24/10287244.aspx), just call `tasks.Add(Task.Run(() => DoWork(fi)));` if you really have to, but the best solution would be find out if you are really CPU bound or IO bound and if you are IO bound just replace the IO calls with async and be done with that.

Comment: @Evk when I run code now if `DoWork` throws an exception it just kills my whole app (because it's not being handled I assume).  I'm trying to find where I can catch that exception.  I also want to know which tasks succeeded and which failed

Comment: Well if that is the exact code you use (I thought there is a typo) - it's wrong, because Task.WhenAll returns you another task which will complete when all other tasks will be completed. You don't use it (don't store it in variable) so it has no effect at all. Instead you want to use Task.WaitAll - it blocks until all tasks will be finished, then throws aggregate exception (if any).

Comment: Make `DoWorkAsync` `async` and handle them inside and return `false`?

Comment: @Evk I updated my question to hopefully reflect the case that I'm experiencing more carefully

Comment: @ScottChamberlain my process is CPU intensive and I want them to run concurrently.  If you believe that `async` is the way to go could you illustrate how that is done properly in this case?

Comment: Why you don't catch your exception inside DoWork? And log/handle it there?

Comment: You say "I'm still seeing behavior that is not caught" - you mean catch handler is not executed? I've just tested it and all goes fine.